# How to remove the element from div?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var aa = 0;
var arr = new Array("one", "two", "three");
var arr1 = new Array("four", "five", "six");

function cl(me) {
    me.clicked = !me.clicked;
    var id = me.id;
    if (me.clicked) {
        if (id == 1000) aa = arr;
        if (id == "one" || id == "two" || id == "three") aa = arr1;
        var s = document.getElementById("sample");
        var d = document.createElement("div");
        d.id = me.id + 1;
        s.appendChild(d);
        for (i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
            var l = document.createElement("label");
            l.innerHTML = aa[i];
            l.id = aa[i];
            l.onclick = function (){cl(this)};
            d.appendChild(l);
        }
    } else {
        var child = document.getElementById(me.id + 1);
        var parent = document.getElementById("sample");
        parent.removeChild(child);
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<label id="1000" onclick="cl(this)">click</label><br><div id="sample"></div>
```

When the label "click" is clicked, three labels "one" "two" "three" are generated successfully.

When I click label "one" labels "four" "five" "six" are generated successfully.

When I again click label "one" "three four five" labels are removed.

But the problem is when I click label "click" and then label "one" .. now when i click "one" again the label "one two three" is alone removed but not "four five six".

Comment: Can you give a more realistic example? because with this code it looks more like a competition to see who can decipher the code. I'm guessing the idea is to have like a tree structure where it opens when you close the top one it closes all below it?

Comment: ya how to make it like a tree structure.............

Comment: Your code is tangled. Do it more obvious. We can help to resolve this local problem, but there will be many problems in your development.

Comment: Separate logic from `document.getElementById`

Comment: @sergzach: You mean: don't use `id`s of DOM elements to store keys to vital parts of the code.

Comment: @sergzach separate logic from document.getElementById means?? what i really want to do??

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: Yes, that too.

Comment: @JScott1989 as u said i have done like a tree structure using checkbox. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167216/how-to-make-this-change-from-checkbox-to-label-element but now i need to change this checkbox to label .. how to do that

Comment: @sergzach any suggestion on this......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167216/how-to-make-this-change-from-checkbox-to-label-element

Comment: @Marcel Korpel any suggestion on this......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167216/how-to-make-this-change-from-checkbox-to-label-element

Answer (score 0):

HTML label elements do not have a *clicked* attribute so it's not a good idea to give them a *clicked* property.

Labels are meant for form controls that don't have a label or caption, such as radio buttons and checkboxes. A more appropriate element here would be a button (either a button or input type button element).

Id attributes must start with a letter, they can't be all numbers.

Browsers will tolerate all of the above, however it's not a good idea to ignore specifications because a browser may be released that adheres to the specification in ways your code doesn't.

I think your issue is that the labels created by *one* look just like the ones created by *four*. If you remove *four* by clicking on *one*, you can't remove the labels it created until you create it again.

Use an element inspector to see what's happening.

Comment: thanks.... any suggestion on this quesiton...........http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167216/how-to-make-this-change-from-checkbox-to-label-element

Comment: thuk - I have no idea what you are actually trying to do (i.e. what is the purpose or goal). All I can see is some code that adds and removes elements. e.g. your requirement might be: "*When a user clicks on a button (0) I want to add 3 more elements (1 to 3). When they click on one of those elements, I want to display 3 more depending on which one they click. If they click on 1 create 4-6, 2 creates 7-9 (replacing 4-6), 4 creates 10-12, etc. If they click on 0, remove all 6 new elements*" or whatever.