# how to make this change from checkbox to label element

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<body>

<script language="javascript">
window.onload=function(){

var container = document.getElementById('container'),
    template = `'<li>\
        <input type="checkbox">\
    </li>\
    <li>\
        <input type="checkbox">\
    </li>\
    <li>\
        <input type="checkbox">\
    </li>';`

container.onchange = function(e) {
    var event = e || window.event,
        target = event.srcElement || event.target;

    if( target.checked && target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div').length === 0 ) {
        var ul = document.createElement('div');
        ul.innerHTML = template;
        target.parentNode.appendChild(ul);
    } else {
        var ul = target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
        target.parentNode.removeChild(ul);
    }
};

}

</script>

    <ul id="container">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
    </li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

i need this program to be changed from checkbox to div element. actually when a checkbox is clicked three checkbox created beneath it and so on and if the parent checkbox is unchecked all the child checkbox are removed. now i need to change this checkbox element to ordinary label element. so that when a label is clicked a three label appears beneath it.. how to do that........

Comment: Labels aren't really supposed to be clickable—they're supposed to trigger or apply focus to a form element such as your checkboxes. Why not use `<a>` links instead? You can style them however you like.

Comment: @Samir Talwar ya thanks i would try that